# SFMC images not rendering in HTML paste email

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, content-builder

I'm having trouble with HTML paste emails in the content builder.

I have an email template in the form of an `index.html` file.

It came along with a bunch of images in an images folder.

When I open the `index.html` in Chrome it opens propely rendering all the images.

I copied the HTML code from `index.html` and pasted into a Create > Email Template > Paste HTML and then uploaded the images to images folder at: Content Builder / my images / Viacom / Template01_Viacom-EditorialGreenApri-8-2019/ 77E / images

Marketing Cloud assigned a URL to every image uploaded as usual.

I tried replacing image file name in the `index.html` template under the `src="image_name"` attribute to the corresponding URL assigned by Content Builder, but the images still don't render after I save the HTML paste template.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share the code you use for embedding the images including the real image URL, so it is possible to help you out.

Comment: I can't post the entire code as it's too long so posting partial code..

Comment: Just one of the lines containing the a-tag is sufficient. Your current post doesn‘t include a single line of code, which makes resolving your issue pure guesswork.

Comment: <td class="fluid-img-1" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center;">
                   <img src="https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3b15707564057e711077/m/1/e22f6df8-5f09-4622-9497-cc99ee0bf4cc.jpg" width="600" editable="true" border="0" alt="" />
                  </td>

Comment: Sorry for some reason the code did not post properly... Here u go...<td class="fluid-img-1" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center;">
                   <img src="https://image.s10.sfmc-content.com/lib/fe3b15707564057e711077/m/1/e22f6df8-5f09-4622-9497-cc99ee0bf4cc.jpg" width="600" editable="true" border="0" alt="" />
                  </td>
It has the https:// part...

Comment: Somehow stachexchange is removing the https:// part

Comment: @Markus Slabina - Any other idea's, thoughts etc ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the **src="image_name"** value with the image URL generated by Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
After uploading an image to Content Builder, you can find the image URL by clicking on the image to view more details. See below: 
[image: SFMC Image Url]

You can read more here: [Insert Content Builder Image in HTML Paste Email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_insert_content_builder_image_in_html_paste_email.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks Cameron! I have done that for all the src attributes within the html code. Still it doesn't render. In fact I tried paste html code in classic content and everything works perfectly. Any other ideas / thoughts?

Comment: Any other thoughts, idea's ??

Comment: Can you update your question with a copy of the HTML code (just the 1 line with the image) you are using; including the correct link to the image?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment now after several days. I ended up logging a case with support and they said that the image sizes are too large. Here's what they had to say "Content Builder renders those images differently than classic email editor.  In viewing the images I see they are really large.  This makes it difficult to have the images appear with dimensions set with percentages. I would recommend either resizing the image to the desired size and import the new images into content builder or try placing the images within content blocks." @Cameron

Comment: @Girish I guess the support is wrong about this, it is a weird issue that happened to me as well, when I am uploading photos in MC, the url generated isn't secure, it is an http not https, and for that reason the images are not rendering, try to upload the photos somewhere else that is secure and try